# What is the best method for using forloop in php with arrays

Tags: php, for-loop

I have two forloop method, Can you guys suggest me which one is best(execution, time, memory usage etc) in practice and explain more about? please ignore `foreach`.

*Method 1:*

```
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){          
        //code here         
    }
```

*Method 2:*

```
    $count = count($array);

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){             
        // code here                
    }
```

Comment: if me prefer number 1

Comment: Define "best" please.

Comment: i will prefer 2 because do not count every time

Answer (score 2):

Instead of going for the above two , You should go for [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

The very first line from the PHP `foreach` documentation...

> The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays.

Comment: Good call, agreed. +1

Comment: agreed +1 nice catch :)

Answer (score 1):

you should use the second method, because 1st method counting array for every iteration

```
$count = count($array);

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){             
    // code here                
}
```

but you can use `foreach` if you want to iterate all element of your array

Comment: also: `for ($i = 0, $count = count($array); $i < $count; $i++ )`

Answer (score 1):

### Method 2

...has (depending on the number of items in `$array`) *much less overhead* than Method 1.

Caching the number of items will restrict PHP from re-evaluating on every pass of the loop and save those CPU cycles and memory for other useful things like...the actual loop.

---

Refer to the [PHP Manual here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) and the 2nd or 3rd (depending where you start counting) paragraph down details this for you.

Answer (score 0):

both syntax are the same nothing different into both loop.

both forloop is best.

instead of forloop i suggest you to foreach loop is the best for array.